# FFMPEG Blending for VP9 format videos

Tags: ffmpeg, moviepy

I get a darker background, almost like a placeholder for the asset that is to be blended, whereas the background should be transparent, and should show the same colour as the rest of the background.

I have two webm vp9 files that I am trying to blend using FFMPEG blending functionality.

One of the videos is a zoom animation that starts from 1 pixel in size and then increases in size to 50 x 50 pixels.

The other is a solid red background video 640 px x 360 px

At frame 1 the result looks like this:-
[image]

At about 0.5 seconds through, the result looks like this:-
[image]

At the end of the sequence, the zoom animation webm fills that darker square you see (50 x 50 pixels).

The code to do the blending of the two webm files looks like this:-

```
filter_complex.extend([
        "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,2)'[out1];",
        '[out1]split[out1_1][out1_2];',
        '[out1_1]crop=50:50:231:251:exact=1,setsar=1[cropped1];',
        '[cropped1][2:v]blend=overlay[blended1];',
        "[out1_2][blended1]overlay=231:251:enable='between(t,0,2)'[out2]"
    ])
```

This overlays a red background onto a white background, making the red background the new background colour.
It then splits the red background into two, so that there is one output for cropping and another output for overlaying.
It then crops the location and size of the layer to be blended out of the red background.  We do this because blending works only on an asset of the same size.
It then performs the blend of the zoom animation onto the cropped background.
It then overlays the blended over the red background

Unfortunately I'm unable to attach videos in stackoverflow, otherwise I would have included them.

The full command looks like this:-

```
ffmpeg -i v1_background.webm -itsoffset 0 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i v2_red.webm -itsoffset 0 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i v3_zoom.webm -filter_complex  "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0[out1];[out1]split[out1_1][out1_2];[out1_1]crop=50:50:231:251:exact=1,setsar=1[cropped1];[cropped1][2:v]blend=overlay[blended1];[out1_2][blended1]overlay=231:251"  output_video_with_blended_overlaid_asset.mp4
```

I have checked the input vp9 webm zoom video file by extracting the first frame of the video

```
ffmpeg -vcodec libvpx-vp9 -i zoom.webm first_frame.png
```

and inspecting the colours in all the channels in GIMP.  The colours (apart from the opaque pixel in the middle) are all zero, including the alpha channel.

Note that I tried adding in all_mode, so that the blend command is blend=all_mode=overlay, however this still shows the darker placeholder under the animation asset.  In other words, this command

```
ffmpeg -i v1_background.webm -itsoffset 0 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i v2_red.webm -itsoffset 0 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i v3_zoom.webm -filter_complex  "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0[out1];[out1]split[out1_1][out1_2];[out1_1]crop=50:50:231:251:exact=1,setsar=1[cropped1];[cropped1][2:v]blend=all_mode=overlay[blended1];[out1_2][blended1]overlay=231:251"  output_video_with_blended_all_mode_overlay_asset.mp4
```

also doesn't work

and trying to convert the formats to rgba first doesn't help either, command below is simplified a bit

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i v2_red.webm -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i v3_zoom.webm -filter_complex "[0:v]format=pix_fmts=rgba[out1];[1:v]format=pix_fmts=rgba[out2];[out1]split[out1_1][out1_2];[out1_1]crop=50:50:0:0:exact=1,setsar=1[cropped1];[cropped1][out2]blend=all_mode=dodge[blended1];[out1_2][blended1]overlay=50:50" output_video_with_blended_all_mode_dodge_rgba_and_alpha_premultiplied_overlay.mp4
```

adding in an alpha premultiply didn't help either

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i v2_red.webm -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i v3_zoom.webm -filter_complex "[0:v]format=pix_fmts=rgba[out1];[1:v]setsar=1,format=pix_fmts=rgba,geq=r='r(X,Y)*alpha(X,Y)/255':g='g(X,Y)*alpha(X,Y)/255':b='b(X,Y)*alpha(X,Y)/255'[out2];[out1]split[out1_1][out1_2];[out1_1]crop=50:50:0:0:exact=1,setsar=1[cropped1];[cropped1][out2]blend=all_mode=dodge[blended1];[out1_2][blended1]overlay=50:50" output_video_with_blended_all_mode_dodge_rgba_and_alpha_premultiplied_overlay.mp4
```

Wondering if there is a workaround I could use so that the background stays transparent?
I was looking for maybe a way of changing the input pixel format in the filter_complex stream to see if that works, but couldn't see anything about this.